Flutter core library mismatch
After a couple of untracked updates, I am getting this error when I try to start debugging my project.

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 Pro in debug mode... Xcode build
done.                                           279.1s Failed to build
iOS app Error (Xcode):
../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/persistent_hash_map.dart:355:1:
Error: Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final',
'var' or a type name.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro.
Clearly there is a mismatch in versions since I didn't touch this file at all. Anyone can help me out of this mystery?

what's your flutter version ?

@Lightn1ng it here Flutter 3.24.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision dec2ee5c1f (8 days ago) • 2024-11-13 11:13:06 -0800
Engine • revision a18df97ca5
Tools • Dart 3.5.4 • DevTools 2.37.3

Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name, error faced due to a mismatch between your Flutter framework version and the Dart version in use. Here's a step-by-step approach to resolve it:
Verify Flutter and Dart Versions
flutter upgrade
flutter doctor

Check if there are any issues, especially with the Dart SDK version compatibility
Clean the Project
flutter clean
flutter pub get

Regenerate iOS Dependencies
cd ios
pod install
cd ..

Check Your Dependencies
flutter pub outdated
flutter pub upgrade

Rebuild the App
flutter run


Thanks but I did all these and still don't work.

@usoysal please take a backup of your project and then delete the pubspec.lock file and ios/Pods folder, then retry above steps

I cleaned the pubspec.lock and pods folder and retried your steps. Still no good news. At this point I am not sure whether it is because this project is broken or my general flutter setup is corrupted. What can I do next?

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/159161, This issue looks similar to yours, try follow the solution on issue, if not works then simply create new project ( default counter) and try running it to make sure your sdk is working fine, then copy all your dependancy to your new project and upgrade your outdated dependancy and try running it if it works fine then, copy your lib folder and update your dependancy related code snippet if needed
